# Python 3 + Pandas + QTableWidget + MySQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

уважаемые гуру!
Есть база данных в ней есть таблица, в которой ведется реестр взвешивания. Поля в таблице следующие: ВЕС, ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ, КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ. Соответственно у КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ есть несколько строк ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ и несколько строк ВЕС.  Мне нужно для  КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ получить "привес", то есть взять последнюю дату взвешивания отнять предыдущие  даты - это и будет "привес". Я делаю следующее:
Получаю два DataFrame с разными датами, потом отнимаю ВЕС. Это работает. НО!!! как мне быть если дат больше чем две? Помогите настроить логику, как лучше выбрать данные с базы что бы в дальнейшем высчитать ПРИВЕС.Возможно как то по другому заполнять таблицу в базе(тогда как ?) В Python и SQL новичок, только начал изучение. Буду признателен за любую помощь.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('реестр взвешивания')
        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.table_widget.clear()
        labels = ['КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ','ВЕС', 'ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ', 'ПРИРОСТ']
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
        db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/base?charset=utf8mb4'
        conn = create_engine(db_connection)
        df = pd.read_sql("""КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ, ВЕС, ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ FROM ТАБЛИЦА ,  WHERE КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ.id = ВЕС.id AND data = '2018-07-20'  """,db_connection)
        df2 = pd.read_sql("""КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ, ВЕС, ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ FROM ТАБЛИЦА ,  WHERE КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ.id = ВЕС.id AND data= '2018-08-29'   """,db_connection)
        full_df = pd.merge(df, df2, on='КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ', how='outer')
        ПРИРОСТ = full_df['ves_y'] - full_df['ves_x']
        full_df['ПРИРОСТ'] = ПРИРОСТ
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(full_df.columns))
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(full_df.index))
        for i in range(len(full_df.index)):
            for j in range(len(full_df.columns)):
        self.table_widget.setItem(i,j,QTableWidgetItem(str(full_df.iloc[i, j])))
```

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных в вопросе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу вам сразу - по другому заполнять базу.
А именно сразу считать "привес", т.е. при занесении в базу данных нового веса сразу проверять наличие истории веса у взвешиваемого, и при наличии - брать последнюю запись и выбирать разницу.

```
Insert into @ТаблицаВеса(
  'КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ',
  'ВЕС', 
  'ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ', 
  'ПРИРОСТ'
) Values(
  'КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ',
  'ВЕС', 
  'ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ', 
  'ПРИРОСТ'
);
```

Прирост можно считать на лету

```
Insert into @ТаблицаВеса(
  'КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ',
  'ВЕС', 
  'ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ', 
  'ПРИРОСТ'
) Values(
  'КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ',
  'ВЕС', 
  'ДАТА ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ', 
  'ВЕС' - 
    (Select 
      `ВЕС` 
     From 
       @ТаблицаВеса 
     where 
       `КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ`='КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ' 
     order by `ДАТА` 
     limit 1
     )
);
```

Comment: Владимир, спасибо за отклик!!! Идея интересная ! Но тогда (на сколько я понял) я не смогу высчитать привес между датами. Допустим Иванов 01.09.18 вес 100   10.09.18 вес 200   19.09.18 вес 300. Я получу привес с 01.09.18 по 19.09.18 равным 200. Но мне бы хотелось еще увидеть привес с 01.09.18 по 10.09.18 равным 100. Возможно ли это реализовать при вашей схеме ? Извините что не уточнил это в вопросе !

Comment: Несовсем так, в предложеном варианте вы сможете увидеть привес за любой промежуток который есть в БД.
Если вам нужно будет привес по одному пользователю то нужно будет сделать запрос по типу:
Select SUM(`ПРИВЕС`) From @ТаблицаВеса where `ДАТА_ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ` >= 01.09.18 and `ДАТА_ВЗВЕШИВАНИЯ` <= 10.09.18 Group by `КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ`

Идея в том что хранится привес с последней даты... т.е. 


`Вес1 = 10кг, привес = 0кг`
`Вес2 = 11кг, привес = 1кг`
`Вес3 = 12кг, привес = 1кг`
`Вес4 = 15кг, привес = 3кг`

Comment: Идея в том чтобы хранить "привес" не с первого взвешивания а с последнего, т.е. разницу между текущим и прошлым взвешиванием(а не первым)

Comment: Спасибо!!! Работает :) только я добавил (Select 
      `ВЕС` 
     From 
       @ТаблицаВеса  as  x 
     where 
       `КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ`='КТО ВЗВЕШИВАЛСЯ' 
     order by `ДАТА` 
     limit 1
     )   по скольку выбивало ошибку  You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause